# What is the name of this ceiling fan part?

Tags: ceiling-fan

I just replaced the light pull switch on my ceiling fan, but I'm having trouble putting the fan back together.  The wires were very short in the original install and I had to leave a little more room to connect the new pull.

The problem is that now the U-shaped bracket that houses the switch won't reconnect because it's too short (1 1/4") to be reattached with the extra wire above it. I have to reinstall it because it is part of the globe attachment.

It's a U-shaped piece with three small holes in each side (for the bolt that attaches to main part of the fan) and it has a hole in the bottom for the pull to drop through.  The hole also allows the male part of the globe connector to go through.

I've been all over the web and can't figure out what this part is called - if I don't know the name I can't order the right part.  I'd probably need one that is 1 1/2" long in order to accommodate the new wires.  Please help!!

[image]

Comment: Photo is necessary; I'm not sure what you are describing.

Comment: That type of part will be very hard to order or buy, your best bet is likely going make what you need, not hard and probably you only need to drill less holes , just where you need them.  Bend it in a vice.

Comment: Yeah, you'll need to fabricate that part. I suspect that your wiring repair should've been done differently so a longer bracket isn't necessary, though. And ten demerits for posting a photo that makes my eyes hurt. :P

Comment: Sorry about that!!  I should have cropped out the crazy light reflection!!

Comment: LOL. No, I meant the completely missed focus.

Comment: It looks a bit different but if the support holds a threaded  shaft it would be a form of "hickey" , it is a electrical term (not a monkey bite that most call a hickey) there is a 3rd type of hickey it is used for bending pipe.

Answer (score 1):

Sad to say but the time that it will take you to find the right part (it looks like a part called a hanger) and track down the obscure supplier who made the piece, organise replacement and shipping and get it back will far exceed the time and cost of you taking a small piece of mild steel plate available from your local home improvement or car parts store, drilling the holes you need and bending it in a vise.

Comment: Thank you!  Now to find someone who knows how to do that!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you check with local electrical contractors, many times they will have a box of assorted parts for lights, fans, etc. that have come out of old units. You could bring your part down to their shop and show them what you mean, and there may be someone there just able and willing to fix things up for you.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you post a picture of the male part that connects to that. I'm going to take a guess that the "male part" can be disassembled and you can easily find a longer "male part".  [image]